# Number of Missing Elements between Two Sets (Objective C)

Tags: objective-c, comparison, nsset

I am attempting to optimize a query where I want a "close enough" response.

I have two sets: A and B.

Set A contains 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8
Set B contains 1, 2, 3, 4

What I'd like to do is check B against A in such a way that it would tell me that 1 element is missing (4 in this case).

Is there a cleaner, more efficient way of doing this besides just going element by element and comparing?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
NSMutableSet *resultSet = [NSMutableSet setWithArray:B];
NSSet *setA = [NSSet setWithArray:A];
[resultSet minusSet:setA];
Array *result = [resultSet allObjects];
```

Reference : [NSMutableSet](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableSet_Class/Reference/NSMutableSet.html)

Comment: A nice solution but you meant it the other way around most likely.
By removing the setA from setB you will know exactly which items from setB are missing in setA. And this will give the desired results.

Comment: @TotumusMaximus : sorry I went out.. so cant able to edit. code thanks for the edit :)

Comment: My heart just skipped a beat.